# model data validation, checking date is less then a date X years ago

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

How can I add model validation to check that the inputted date is less then a date X years, X days, or whatever ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do that is to create a new custom attribute to deal with this
Here's a sample code

```
 public class CheckDate: ValidationAttribute {
    public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        if (dt >= YOURDAteTime) {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Make sure your date is >= YOURDateTime");
    }

}
```

another way  is to do the validation at the client side . here's a `JavaScript` that you can implement (it has a lot of other useful features) 
The method you are looking for is `Date.compare`
here's an example: `Date.compare(date1, date2);`

> Return Value:
>
> > {Number} -1 = date1 is lessthan date2. 0 = values are equal. 1 = date1
> >     is greaterthan date2.

Comment: The first one was just what I was looking for, but would you mind posting an example of the client side javascript turning on the validation messages?